# Create multiple VM's in Azure with different configuration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create two vm's with terraform in Azure. I have configured two "azurerm_network_interface" but when I try to apply the changes, I receive an error. Do you have any idea? Is there any issue if I try to create them on different regions?

The error is something like: vm2-nic was not found azurerm_network_interface

```
# Configure the Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  version = "=2.10.0"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "north-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "North Europe"
  resource_group_name = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                    = "test-pip"
  location                = "North Europe"
  resource_group_name     = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  allocation_method       = "Static"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 30

  tags = {
    environment = "dev01"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  for_each            = var.locations
  name                = "${each.key}-nic"
  location            = "${each.value}"
  resource_group_name = var.azurerm_resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  for_each              = var.locations
  name                  = "${each.key}t-vm"
  location              = "${each.value}"
  resource_group_name   = var.azurerm_resource_group_name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main[each.key].id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_D2s_v3"
...
```

Error:

```
Error: Error creating Network Interface "vm2-nic" (Resource Group "candidate-d7f5a2-rg"): network.InterfacesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidResourceReference" Message="Resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/north-network/subnets/internal referenced by resource /subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/vm2-nic was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region." Details=[]

  on environment.tf line 47, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main":
  47: resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation each NIC attached to a VM must exist in the same location (Region) and subscription as the VM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/network-overview.

If you can re-create the NIC in the same location as the VM or create the VM in the same location as the NIC that will likely solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, daodennis. The NIC's have different locations, but every nic has the same location with the corresponded VM. Is it not in order?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `for_each` and in the `resource "azurerm_network_interface"`, it will create two NICs in the `location = "${each.value}"` while the subnet or VNet has a fixed region "North Europe". You need to create the NICs or other Azure VM related resources like subnets in the same region, you could change the codes like this,

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "myrg"
  location = "West US"
}

variable "locations" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    vm1 = "North Europe"
    vm2 = "West Europe"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  for_each            = var.locations
  name                = "${each.key}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "${each.value}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  for_each             = var.locations
  name                 = "${each.key}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main[each.key].name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  for_each                = var.locations
  name                    = "${each.key}-pip"
  location                = "${each.value}"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  allocation_method       = "Static"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 30

}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  for_each            = var.locations
  name                = "${each.key}-nic"
  location            = "${each.value}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal[each.key].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.example[each.key].id
  }
}
```

Comment: network_interface_ids = azurerm_network_interface.main[each-key].id, now I receive here another error:Error: Invalid reference

  on environment.tf line 70, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main":
  70:   network_interface_ids = azurerm_network_interface.main[each-key].id

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.

Comment: that is another new question. Please accept this and post a new thread